# Ext JS 6.5.2 Comobobox and ArrayStore load issues

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-modern

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do with Sencha Ext JS 6.5.2 Modern:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2b2i

I am trying to use an ArrayStore to load some values into the combobox. When I click on the drop down arrow, or search, I get an error stating that:

```
Cannot read property 'getFilters' of null
```

The problems seems that it is not loading the data correctly, and 'me.getStore()' returns null.

Am I not using the 'store' properly?

Answer (score 2):

After some digging into the API and trying to find numerous examples across the web, I believe I figured it out.

1. I was setting the 'store' key as a string. *slap head*, instead of a config object. I changed that from:`store: 'states'` to `store: { type: 'states' }`
2. I also had the wrong field specified in the model: `displayAS` vs `displayAs`.

once I did this, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

- Please check the docs to find that ExtJS stores have no `alias` config. You may want to change your store identification from `alias` to `storeId`.
- Also, check the [`store` config of the combobox](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.field.ComboBox.html#cfg-store) to find that ExtJS takes "either a Store instance, configuration object or store ID", but does not instantiate a new store by alias.
  So you have to instantiate a new `states` store instance before your combobox is rendered. For the instantiation of stores of which only one instance should exist throughout the app, I can recommend adding them to the [`stores`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.app.Application.html#cfg-stores) config of the `Application`.

Comment: I was about to reply to my own question. 'alias' is allowed in the store config. The 'Setup' page under "Guides' for 6.5.2 uses it. I actually solved the issue. The issue was in fact, the 2nd bullet point.